# Swiftmailer display template content twice

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, yii2-basic-app

I have controller like this :

```
$mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html'=>'@app/mail/layouts/html',],['content'=>$_POST["msg"]])
   ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['admin_email']=>Yii::$app->params['admin_name'])
   ->setTo($_POST["to"])
   ->setSubject($_POST["subject"]);
$mail->send();
```

And in my mail template which located at `@app/mail/layouts/html`

```
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
This is Email Introduction
<?= $content ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
```

Email successfuly sent, but when i'm going to check Inbox `"This is Email Introduction"` generated twice. You can check [my latest message here](https://www.mailinator.com/inbox.jsp?to=suhendra).

My Inbox get message like this :

```
This is Email Introduction 
This is Email Introduction 
ini pesan Pesan ke dua
```

Any wrong with my codes ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I found the answer. This is my config `@app/config/web.php` on `component's` section :

```
    'components'=>[
        'mailer' => [
           'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
           'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
           'useFileTransport' => false,
           'transport' => [
              'class'=>'Swift_SmtpTransport',
              'host'=>'host.domain.tld', //sample
              'username'=>'my@emaul.com', //sample email
              'password'=>'~!@#$%%^&&', // sample password
              'port'=>'465',
              'encryption'=>'ssl',
           ],
       ],
    ],
```

I forgot This section `'viewPath' => '@app/mail'` as main layout for Swiftmailer, and will be send when we calling `send()` function.
So when we have code like this :

```
$mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose(['html'=>'@app/mail/layouts/html',],['content'=>$_POST["msg"]])
   ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['admin_email']=>Yii::$app->params['admin_name'])
   ->setTo($_POST["to"])
   ->setSubject($_POST["subject"]);
$mail->send();
```

part `['html'=>'@app/mail/layouts/html']` tell us which **VIEW** will we use